# piecewise linear approximation

Tags: matlab, geometry, curve-fitting, approximation, piecewise

I'm studying the vertical profile of a railway. In a nutshell it is composed by a succession of straights and circles (tangents to the straights between which they are included). My data set is composed by survey points, measured along the railway with an uncertainty. My goal is to approximate this data set with a succession of straights and tangent circles (with the center on the bisector of the two straights in which it's included), such that certain constraints are respected (the most important concerns deviations, so i have to set lower and upper bounds).
I'm developing an algorithm that recognize (or try to) if the survey points belong to a straight or a circle (simply, computing the change rate of gradient). After having cataloged all the points in the single lines and circles (I have the point group that belongs to the first straight, the point group that belongs to the second straights and the point group that belongs to the first circle, tangent to the first to straights.... and so on...). So, I need to approximate all the point group that belongs to tangents with a continuous piecewise linear function, respecting lower and upper bounds constraints.

Could someone help me to implement in Matlab this continuous piecewise linear approximation, or maybe with some alternative ideas?

Comment: look up "arc spline fitting".  googling "arc spline" brings up *"Arc splines are G1 continuous curves made of circular arcs and straight-line segments."*

Comment: and googling *"G1 continuous curves made of circular arcs and straight-line segments"* brings up e.g. this 1992 paper, ["Approximation of discrete data by G1 arc splines"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/001044859290047E) which seems to be exactly what you're asking about.